# How to execute a command on the server with Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ssh, capistrano

I have a very simple task called update_feeds:

```
desc "Update feeds"
task :update_feeds do
  run "cd #{release_path}"
  run "script/console production"
  run "FeedEntry.update_all"
end
```

Whenever I try to run this task, I get the following message:

```
[out :: mysite.com] sh: script/console: No such file or directory
```

I figured it's because I am not in the right directory, but trying

```
run "cd ~/user/mysite.com/current"
```

instead of

```
run "cd #{release_path}"
```

Also fails. Running the exact same commands manually (through ssh) works perfectly.
Why can't capistrano properly `cd` (change directory) into the site directory to run the command?

Thanks!

---

**Update:** Picked an answer, and thank you so much to all who replied.
The best answer may actually be the [one on server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/175689/how-to-execute-a-command-on-the-server-with-capistrano), though the gist of both (the one on server fault and the one on stack overflow) is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use script/runner. It starts an instance of the app to execute the method you want to call. Its slow though as it has to load all of your rails app.

```
~/user/mysite.com/current/script/runner -e production FeedEntry.update_all 2>&1
```

You can run that from the capistrano task.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot imagine that you would be able to remotely log into rails console from capistrano. I suggest you call your model method from a rake task.

[How do I run a rake task from Capistrano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312214/how-do-i-run-a-rake-task-from-capistrano)

As for the latter part of your question, are you logging into the server with the same user account as capistrano?