# Capsitrano deploy recipe : after deploy file listing and modifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm currently working on a multi-stage recipe for Capistrano that would, ideally, after deploy, make wise use of the yui compressor for all css and js.

Here's what I currently came up to :

```
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup", "minifier:compress"
# Task to minify via Yui-compressor
# Uses compressor bundled with application in #{application}/lib/yuicompressor
namespace :minifier do

def minify(files)
 files.each do |file|
   cmd = "java -jar lib/yuicompressor/build/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar #{file} -o #{file}"
   puts cmd
   ret = system(cmd)
   raise "Minification failed for #{file}" if !ret
 end
end

desc "minify"
 task :compress do
 minify_js
 minify_css
end

desc "minify javascript"
 task :minify_js do
 minify(Filelist['public/js/**/*.js'])
end

desc "minify css"
 task :minify_css do
  minify(Filelist['public/css/**/*.css'])
 end
end
```

What's really puzzling me is the

```
uninitialized constant Capistrano::Configuration::Filelist (NameError)
```

I get as soon as Capistrano gets to the point.
As a total newbie to Ruby, Rails, and Capistrano, I understand for some reason FileList isn't a common Capistrano method, but can't figure out what to replace it with.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you mean ::Rake::Filelist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is conceptually wrong, it will run on local system (the one from which you're deploying), because you're call `system`, you should use the `run` method which run commands remotely.

```
def minify(files)
 files.each do |file|
   cmd = "java -jar lib/yuicompressor/build/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar #{file} -o #{file}"
   puts cmd
   ret = system(cmd) # *** SYSTEM RUN LOCAL COMMANDS ***
   raise "Minification failed for #{file}" if !ret
 end
end
```

That said, I will change that code with shell scripting, something like (untested)

```
task :minify
  cmd = "java -jar lib/yuicompressor/build/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar"
  run "find #{current_path}/public/css/ -name '*.css' -print0 | xargs -0 -I file #{cmd} file -o file"
  run "find #{current_path}/public/js/ -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 -I file #{cmd} file -o file"
end
```

or if you prefer to use ruby to program it, you should move the code into a rake task (which you can try and debug locally) and then invoke it with Capistrano: [How do I run a rake task from Capistrano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312214/how-do-i-run-a-rake-task-from-capistrano)