# Run remote rake task from capistrano, cap deploy bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, capistrano

I followed the answer from @Coward in this topic: [How do I run a rake task from Capistrano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312214/how-do-i-run-a-rake-task-from-capistrano)
to add a customizing task `rake:invoke` in my `deploy.rb` to be able to invoke rake tasks remotely.

It works perfect on it's own part, but I get following error when my `cap deploy` processing is doing `assets:precompile`

```
[mydomain.com] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2@ziya' -c 'cd /var/deploy/ziya/releases/20120223100338 && #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x007ff2b4a4bad8> RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'
 ** [out :: my domain.com] bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
    command finished in 1265ms
```

it's like kind of injection something, but I just can't find out what's going wrong in my deploy.rb

**deploy.rb:**

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
require "rvm/capistrano"                  # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2@ziya'
set :use_sudo, true

require "bundler/capistrano"

set :stages, %w(staging production)
set :default_stage, "production"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :application, "my application"

# ssh to the deploy server
default_run_options[:pty] = true

# setup scm:
set :repository,  "mygiturl"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm_username, "myusernmae"
set :scm, :git
set :scm_verbose, "true"
set :branch, "master"
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

set(:releases_path)     { File.join(deploy_to, version_dir) }
set(:shared_path)       { File.join(deploy_to, shared_dir) }
set(:current_path)      { File.join(deploy_to, current_dir) }
set(:release_path)      { File.join(releases_path, release_name) }

set :deploy_to, "/var/deploy/#{application}"

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  task :bootstrap do
    run "cd #{release_path}; rake bootstrap:all RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end

  task :import_all do
    run "cd #{release_path}; rake import:pages RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
    run "cd #{release_path}; rake import:legacy_all RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end  

  task :import_pages do
    run "cd #{release_path}; rake import:pages RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
end

namespace :rake do  
  desc "Run a task on a remote server."  
  # run like: cap staging rake:invoke task=a_certain_task  
  task :invoke do  
    run("cd #{deploy_to}/current; /usr/bin/env rake #{ENV['task']} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}")  
  end  
end
```

But if I move the `task :invoke` into `namespace :deploy`, drop the `namespace :rake`, then everything is ok, it's so confusing..

Answer (score 2):

This happen since Capistrano in its source [declare rake as internal variable](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L32), in this way [you can override](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L371) which command is used as rake command line using a `set :rake` instruction in your deploy file.

However, because of capistrano internals, when you declare a `rake` namespace it will take precedence on the declared rake variable. So when capistrano execute its recipe to precompile assets and it [builds the required command line](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/assets.rb#L41) the `rake` variable instead of returning the `"rake"` string returns your declared namespace converted to a string. You can see it in this part of the built command line:

```
 ... && #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x007ff2b4a4bad8> RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'
```

This obviously cause a shell syntax error and this is the reason of why changing the namespace solves your issue.