# Rails - Run Rake tasks with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, capistrano

Im scratching my head here wondering if I'm barking up the wrong tree.  I have a server which I've deployed a Rails app onto using Capistrano.  Recently I added a new data type to one of the models, and now I need to run a Rake task to update the existing records.

After a lot of Googling I'm starting to wonder if people use Rake tasks with Capistrano.  Some forum posts from 2013 or so mention that Capistrano supports the .rake extension.  Whereas other posts I've found indicate that Capistrano has its own task automation system, and is incompatible with rake.

I found [Cape](https://github.com/njonsson/cape), but I'm unsure if this is what I'm looking for as it seems to convert Rake tasks into cap recipes.  Its possible I'm mistaken on this point, I really don't have any experience working with Capistrano or even working in the full stack spectrum.

What I'm wondering is this: How do I run a simple Rake task on my remote server?

Some quick points for clarity, I've installed the app on the latest Ubuntu LTS, 14.10 if memory serves.  I followed the tutorial found [here](http://www.rubytreesoftware.com/courses/deploy-ruby-on-rails-tutorial).  I have full sudo access and I can ssh into the server.

thanks in advance for helping a noob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a rake task from Capistrano?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312214/how-do-i-run-a-rake-task-from-capistrano)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to update models, you can of course write a Rails migration - this will ensure that it's run if it hasn't been run yet.

The easiest way to execute a rake task on the server would be just via ssh if it's a one-time task. See the last paragraph in the tutorial you mentioned:

```
cd /opt/www/testapp/current ; bin/rake RAILS_ENV=production db:seed
```

To answer your original question about rake: you can execute rake tasks via capistrano similar to how you would execute it locally, only within the capistrano script. Here's an example:

deploy.rb:

```
namespace :rake do
  desc "My task"
  task :my_task do
    on roles(:app) do
      within "#{current_path}" do
        with rails_env: :production do
          execute :rake, "my_task"
          # !!!see NOTE at end of answer!!!
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can view all your cap tasks via `cap -T` locally. The capistrano task I wrote above should show up as `cap tasks:my_rake_task`.

If you want to be ably to run *any* available rake task without configuring, do the following:

```
namespace :rake do
  desc "Invoke rake task"
  task :invoke do
    on roles(:app) do
      within "#{current_path}" do
        with rails_env: :production do
          execute :rake, ENV['task']
          # !!!see NOTE at end of answer!!!
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can write:

```
cap production deploy:invoke task=my:rake:task
```

NOTE: you might want to replace the execution line with

```
run "bin/rake RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} #{ENV['task']}"
```

to use the same syntax as the tutorial (without the binstubs you might need to configure capistrano/bundler and capistrano/rbenv first ...)

Comment: You have `namespace :rake`, but your example command uses the deploy namespace.  I had to use the deploy namespace for capistrano to use it.

Answer (score 5):

## Check out [`capistrano-rake`](https://github.com/sheharyarn/capistrano-rake)

Once installed, run any rake task on your production/staging servers without messy capistrano recipes by simply doing this:

```
$ cap production invoke:rake TASK=your:rake:task
```

---

*Full Disclosure: I wrote it*